# nested IOException catch for socket close

Tags: java, sockets, exception, ioexception

I write to socket with:

```
OutputStream socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socketStream.write(buf);
```

But this can throw `IOException`, so I do:

```
try {
  OutputStream socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
  socketStream.write(buf);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // logging
} finally {
  socket.close();
}
```

1. But `socket.close` also force me to catch `IOException`! So do I need `try ... catch` it again in `finally`?
2. When catch `IOException` from `close`, it mean socket *not closed*? So try `close` again? Or what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close()` throws `IOException` because closing something usually implies calling `flush()`, and flushing might fail. For example, if you lose network connectivity and issue `socket.close()`, you cannot flush whatever you have buffered, so `flush()` will throw an exception. Because data might be lost, the exception is checked, so you are forced to deal with that possibility.

I think the best way to deal with this is:

```
try {
    OutputStream socketStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    socketStream.write(buf);
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // try to deal with your I/O error; do logging
} finally {
    closeSilently(socket);
}
...
// Somewhere else, usually part of an utility JAR like Apache Commons IO
public static void closeSilently(Socket s) {
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // do more logging if appropiate
        }
    }
}
```

This code will work normally in the common case. If something goes wrong (even inside `close()`), it will allow you to catch the exception and do something before unconditionally closing your socket and swallowing everything it might throw.

Comment: What if socket passed to closeSilently is opened with error (i.e. connect failed), is safe call close on it? i think it won't be null

Comment: It should be safe. In most sane APIs, calling `close()`is a no-op when the object is not in open state.

Answer (score 1):

The Exception thrown by close can usually just be ignored (well you can log it). That's pretty much the same as throwing an exception in a destructor in C++ - there's not much (usually nothing) you can do about it and trying to close it again is nonsensical. Cleanup throwing exceptions is usually bad design - you can implement cleanup code for the cleanup but that's a recursive problem, in the end you'll just have to except that you can't handle it.

Comment: So why does it throw **checked** exception? - I can't ignore it

Comment: Well an unchecked exception would be a really bad idea (that's against the informal contract of unchecked exceptions being programmer errors). So, no exception? Surely a possibility, but there are scenarios where you want to handle such an exception (and let it be just log it). But just because it throws an exception doesn't mean you can't use an empty catch block to ignore it..